# In AWS amazon, How can I keep my files updated in route53 to my bucket in S3?

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-hosting

I have a basic account in AWS amazon to host my personal site.

But I am always confusing, with the versions.
My domain name is www.ladimela.com.
After I upload something to my bucket, everything works fine, for example:
If I upload a html file, to my bucket,
I can see it though my domain without problem.
But if I update it, or even delete it, my domain won't change.
It seems that only create new files will update my domain.

to show you examples, I uploaded a html file named questionforstackoverflow.html, with very simple content:

    Hello, this is the old version

then I delete it, and uploaded a new html file to replace it, with the same name, and very simple content as well:

    This is the new version

Now, my domain is still the old version, which doesn't exist in my S3 bucket.
here is it:
www.ladimela.com/questionforstackoverflow.html

But I can view my new version with https://s3.amazonaws.com/... 
here is it:
s3.amazonaws.com/ladimela/questionforstackoverflow.html

This is my first question in Stackoverflow, I hope someone can help me, thanks!

Comment: Caching most likely?

Comment: likely, but it is not cache, I cleared caches and it doesn't work. But in s3.amazonaws.com/ladimela/questionforstackoverflow.html, even i don't clear cache, it will update every time i modify the file.

Comment: You've cleared your local cache yes, but this could be server side caching on their end. At the time of writing the page on your domain had the new text on it.

Comment: oh yes, this might be true, because now both of them are showing new version to me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Both the urls give html which says, **new version.**
Try clearing the browser cache before reloading the hosted site.

Comment: really? But here even with other device, http://www.ladimela.com/questionforstackoverflow.html shows "old version". I cleared cache but not solved